# Laravel hasMany relation with custom query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a table for `Product Orders`. An order belongs to a `Customer` (Buyer) whose id is in the order record. I can get customer orders with default `hasMany` relation

```
// Customer model
public function orders() {
  return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}
```

In the other hand, as each `Product` belongs to a `Customer` (different from the one whose id is in the order) `Customer` (Seller), I want the other `Customer` can see the list of `Order`s which have his `Product` in it.

I want to get list of customer `Order`s when either he is the seller or the buyer. I want to create a custom relation or modify a relation to achieve the result.

Is it possible to achieve this with Laravel's relations?

Customers table:

```
---------------------------
| customer_id |   name    | 
---------------------------
| 1           | seller    |
| 2           | buyer     |
```

Products table:

```
---------------------------------------
| product_id  |   name    | seller_id |
---------------------------------------
| 101         | iPhone 6s |   1       |
```

Orders Table

```
----------------------------------------
| order_id  | customer_id | product_id |
----------------------------------------
| 500       | 2           |   101      |
```

When using simple `hasMany` relation, buyer will see order 500 in his orders list.

```
$buyer->orders();
```

I want to create a single relation that when I call it from seller's side, he can see order 500 in his orders list.

```
$seller->orders();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you've defined all the relationships. Use `where()` to filter by a buyer and `orWhereHas()` to filter by a seller:

```
Order::where('customer_id', auth()->id())
    orWhereHas('product.seller', function($q) {
        $q->where('id', auth()->id());
    })
    ->get();
```

If you have other where clauses in the query, wrap `where()` and `orWhereHas()` with the `where()` closure.

Comment: I know how to retrieve data with query builder, I want it to be a eloquent `Relation` so I can use it in other Models

Comment: I like to create a custom relationship in my model, but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: @Hadu you can use this code as a local scope, but you can't define a relationship like `hasMnyThrough` or similar, for this case.

Comment: Isn't there any way to define custom Relations in laravel

Comment: using it as a scope was a great idea! +1 for that